# how to interpolate string returned from JSON object in angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, string-interpolation

I have a requirement where I have json Object with key value pair and inside value I have a string where I have to add dynamic data in between of string.

**messages.json**

```
{
"US": "you are logged in from {{united states}}",
"IN": "you are logged in from {{India}}"
}
```

in my component.ts file I have data with `{"US": "United states", "IN: "India"}`. now when user logs in to application I get "US" or "IN", now based on that i have to show the message from **message.json**.

the problem statement is, inside my **message.json** file I don't want to repeat message for each country, instead I want to insert country name dynamically inside message and display it to the user. how can I achieve it in angular

Note: this is a sample json.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make your json as below

let object = {"US": "you are logged in from {{Name}}"}
// based on the country name you need to replace your {{Name}} with the dynamic string.
object['US'].replace('{{Name}}','Dynamic string');